# How to set font of class names and methods in phpstorm

Tags: fonts, phpstorm

I want to set font of class names and class methods as bold. Only for that two items in any language. But it seems that each language specific class names are inherited from "Identifier" item but not from "language defaults" class names. So it sets bold either class name and many other identifiers. At the other way I dont know if its possible to override font feature per item. I couldnt do it so far.

I just try to make the same colors&fonts as they are at NetBeans by default

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-137

Comment: I see, voted for the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is missing in the present PhpStorm version, you can [vote for it](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-137).